# Loop through attribute ids of FeatureLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Would there be a way to loop through the `definitionExpression` ids without having to manually specify?

I have tried to console log `SeismicData`, but for some reason I am not finding a collection of ids but only one.. I would like to loop through and store these ids in variables so I don't have to constantly update manually when data refreshes. Any idea how to obtain these?

```
const SeismicData = new FeatureLayer({
title: "MMI - Shake Intensity",
url: "https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/USGS_Seismic_Data_v1/FeatureServer/1/",
outFields: ["id","mag","eventTime","url"],
popupTemplate: popupUSGS
});

SeismicData.definitionExpression = "grid_value > 2",
SeismicData.definitionExpression = "id = 'us70008jr5'", <---- i.e. here,
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need all the ids up front, you can query the layer when your application starts and store them somewhere. The FeatureLayer query supports [`returnDistinctValues`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html#returnDistinctValues) so you can get the distinct ids.

Something like this maybe.

```
layer
  .load()
  .then(() => {
    // create a query from the layer
    const query = layer.createQuery();
    query.returnDistinctValues = true;
    query.where = "grid_value > 2"; // or 1=1 if you need them all
    // the field you want distinct values for
    query.outFields = ["id"];
    return layer.queryFeatures(query);
  })
  .then(({ features }) => {
    // extract the ids to a list
    const ids = features.map(({ attributes }) => attributes.id);
    return ids;
  })
  .then((ids) => {
    // You can store them how you want, in this case,
    // I put them in a dropdown select menu
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    ids.forEach((id) => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = id;
      option.innerText = id;
      fragment.appendChild(option);
    });
    list.appendChild(fragment);
    map.add(layer);
});
```

Then you can update the definitionExpression during the lifecycle of your app based on some action. [Here is a demo](https://codepen.io/odoe/pen/MWKyeOx?editors=0010) that does it based on selecting a new value from the select menu.

Comment: Thanks so much this is cool; but I keep seeming to hit the same road block - I cant seem to 'add/display by attribute' 'one after another' -- or for instance add them along the way -- I can filter one at a time, show one, but I can't seem to 'add to the map by attribute id' one at a time (i.e. like via checkboxs)